# IE7 won't display bmp files with encoded filenames

Tags: html, unicode, internet-explorer-7

I have a test page that displays two images. One called hello.bmp and another called 徘吐驴欸觰.bmp (this is a random collection of Chinese characters - apologies if it means something weird). For the latter image, I use an encoded format in the page's HTML.

The html is pretty straight forward:

```
<img src="%E5%BE%98%E5%90%90%E9%A9%B4%E6%AC%B8%E8%A7%B0.bmp" />
<img src="hello.bmp" />
```

In Internet explore 7, the encoded filepath does not display (Red x). All other browsers display it.

Does anyone know what would cause this? Can it be avoided?

Comment: Compare the access logs of the server when IE and not-IE hit it. Is IE 404ing? Is the path different?

Comment: @MM: Are you really using .bmp's on your site?

Comment: @Quentin - no 404's. This is a local file, as are the images. hello.bmp is loaded correctly, but the encoded path next to it fails.

Comment: @PeeHaa - don't worry, I'm not actually using bmp's on my site:) I'm trying to diagnose a problem with downloading bmp's (long story). This is a test page to determine what is different about IE that prevents it from successfully downloading the files.

Comment: @MM — does this need to work locally? If you are testing in advance of doing stuff on the web, then stop, get a web server running, and test there. The file system and security differences between HTTP and non-HTTP stuff makes doing testing off the hard disk a nightmare.

Comment: Generally I would, but it shouldn't affect this situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Character encoding of `file:///` URLs works differently across browsers on Windows.

Windows filenames are natively Unicode-based, so when you use a URL, which is byte-based, it has to convert that sequence of bytes to Unicode characters using an encoding. What encoding? There is no standard to say, but there are two obvious possibilities:

- UTF-8, since it covers everything and is a popular default encoding, also used by the IRI standard for putting Unicode in URIs;
- the (misleadingly-named) “ANSI” code page, which is an arbitrary default that varies from system to system. On a Western European Windows install it will be code page 1252 (which is similar to ISO-8859-1); on a Chinese Windows install it will be code page 936 (similar to GB2312).

The ANSI code page is a pain because you never know what it's going to be, it's *never* UTF-8, and if your filename contains characters that don't exist in ANSI—which will certainly be the case if you have the filename `徘吐驴欸觰.bmp` on a Western Windows install—you can't access the file at all.

So which do the browsers use?

- IE: ANSI code page
- Safari/Opera: UTF-8
- Chrome/Firefox: UTF-8, unless the bytes are not a valid UTF-8 sequence, in which case the ANSI code page is used instead.

So in conclusion, you can't reliably use non-ASCII characters in file:/// URLs at all.

This is in contrast to HTTP. The IIS web server, for example, has the same UTF-8-with-fallback-to-ANSI behaviour as Chrome and Firefox. Non-ASCII characters via IRI and a suitably-configured server are fine, but not the local filesystem.

(On non-Windows platforms filenames are natively bytes, usually representing UTF-8-encoded characters, but still bytes. Oo there is no ambiguity between the filesystem names and the byte-based URL %-sequences.)

<sub>die ANSI code page die. Why won't Microsoft kill you? You have long outstayed your welcome. You ruin everything.</sub>

Comment: +1, but regarding your fine print, killing `Windows-1252` now would break many, many programs that have been running quietly (and *successfully*) since the Dreaded Nineties (and even earlier). Why would Microsoft shoot themselves in their collective foot like that? The .NET platform is an appropriate medium-term response IMHO, but legacy code still is legacy code... and it must keep running :)